# Firefox add-on that suspends inactive tabs, to use less memory

Tags: firefox

Is there any Firefox extension similar to Chrome's [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg)?

Basically it suspends tabs that are not actively being used, allowing you to have a lot of tabs without consuming all your memory and CPU processing.

Comment: For Firefox 57+ I guess?

Comment: Correct, Firefox 57.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Tab Suspender (memory saver)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-suspender-tab-unloader/)** seems to be a pretty good alternative.

Comment: Please explain its features, and how it differs from what the asker wants. Thanks!

Comment: The author of that add-on states "This extension is deprecated; For FF >= 58 switch to my native tab suspender add-on" (which is the one mentioned in [@kenorb's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/48470/8558).

Comment: While deprecated it's technically still compatible with FF 58

Answer (score 9):

There are several options:

- [Auto Tab Discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard/) (Compatible with Firefox Quantum)

  > Use native tab discard method to automatically reduce memory usage of inactive tabs.
- [One Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/onetab/) (Compatible with Firefox Quantum)

  > OneTab - Too many tabs? Convert tabs to a list and reduce browser memory
- [Dormancy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dormancy/) (Compatible with Firefox Quantum) [Experimental]

  > 'Retires' tabs that have gone unused for a while, freeing up that memory. It then restores the tabs to life when accessed.
- [UnloadTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unloadtab/) (Not compatible with Firefox Quantum)

  > Unload inactive tabs, save resources.
- [Suspend Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/suspend-tab/) (Not compatible with Firefox Quantum)

  > Suspends background old tabs automatically to save memory usage.