# Firefox add-on that suspends inactive tabs, to use less cpu

Tags: firefox

Looking at [Firefox add-on that suspends inactive tabs, to use less memory](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47220/firefox-add-on-that-suspends-inactive-tabs-to-use-less-memory) I tried out [Dormancy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dormancy/). It does what it says on the box, but to me the reload is fairly annoying. I would rather just have the tab be inactive (i.e. get no CPU power) but stay in memory (and the let the virtual memory subsystem swap that out eventually due to inactivity).

So I am looking for an extension that will immediately stop running anything in non-active tabs - preferably with an easy way to whitelist a tab.

Does such a beast exist?