# A Firefox addon to suspend inactive tabs to disk which does not require the tab to be reloaded by swapping from RAM to disk (to reduce memory use)

Tags: firefox, memory-management, caching, performance

Is there a Firefox addon (or anything built into Firefox) that allows suspending inactive tabs which does not require the tabs to be reloaded when restoring/resuming them? I think this could be achieved by moving the relevant data from memory to swap space or the disk cache in general.

All addons I found so far unload the tabs and require it to be reloaded instead of simply restoring it (similar to when one clicks active tabs; favicon, data entered into text-fields, page-settings, etc would all remain).

This would allow freeing up memory and CPU and prevent network requests from being sent in between. There could also be whitelist for specific websites and domains and a setting for a timer when tabs become "inactive". Making the data available from SSD swap would probably fairly performant even if it's not moved to memory before the tab is "restored".

Users already asked about similar addons [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47220/firefox-add-on-that-suspends-inactive-tabs-to-use-less-memory) but none of these seem to suspend to disk but require a reload of the tab. This seems to be the case for "Discard Tab", "Auto Tab Discard", "UnloadTabs", "Dormancy" and "New Tab Suspender".

If there's another place to ask about this please add a comment. Happy new year!